# Serilog logging extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-core

I've been using this extension in almost all of my projects. What's your opinion? Do you think there is something else to add or to be improved? The idea is to ignore all default ASP.NET messages that are there by default and if optionally to override stuff via configuration. I actually override `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware` via appsettings.

```cs
public static class LoggingExtensions
{
    private const string SectionName = "Serilog";

    public static IHostBuilder AddCustomLogging(
        this IHostBuilder builder,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        LogEventLevel minLevelLocal = LogEventLevel.Information)
    {
        const string outputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}";

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Is(minLevelLocal)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration, SectionName)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithProcessName()
            .Enrich.WithMemoryUsage()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
            .CreateLogger();

        return builder.UseSerilog();
    }
}
```

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Debug",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.4.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Memory" Version="1.0.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" Version="2.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I don't see any correlation or trace id. Is it on purpose or left out for brevity?

Comment: @PeterCsala, haven't really used them. I'm reading https://www.code4it.dev/blog/serilog-correlation-id right now.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I published this extension as a private NuGet package and I technically do `builder.Host.AddCustomLogging(builder.Configuration);` in every single API that I work on, it's more like a shared business logic between multiple projects.

Comment: Ohh okay, so you don't want to do distributed tracing to correlate separate log entries.

Comment: @PeterCsala, yeah, at least not at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### constants of `LoggingExtensions`

- I don't know why did you declare `SectionName` on class level whereas the `outputTemplate` inside the `AddCustomLogging` method
- I think both could be defined on class level

```
const string SectionName = "Serilog";
const string OutputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}";
```

#### `AddCustomLogging`'s parameters

- As I stated earlier I don't think the `configuration` parameter is necessary since you can reach it through the `builder` parameter
- For me this `minLevelLocal` name seems a bit weird

  - What does `local` mean in this context?
- Allowing the user to specify the default log level seems odd to me

  - Either allow to specify all three log levels
  - Or do not allow any of them, since you can set them via the json config

#### `UseSerilog`

- It seems a really strict restriction to use only serilog
- In order to allow flexibility I would suggest to add an other method which would register serilog as one of the log providers (`AddSerilog`)

```
public static IHostBuilder RegisterSerilogCustomLogging(this IHostBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
public static IHostBuilder AddSerilogCustomLogging(this IHostBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
```

#### Enrichers, Filters or sinks

- Your current design does not allow the user to add something to the predefined setup
- If you want to allow that flexibility then you can do the following:

```
public static IHostBuilder RegisterSerilogCustomLogging(
    this IHostBuilder builder, 
    IConfiguration configuration, 
    Action<LoggerConfiguration>? configureLogger = null) 

{
    ...
    var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
      ...
      .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate);
    
    configureLogger?.Invoke(loggerConfig);
    
    Log.Logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
    builder.UseSerilog();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! `builder.Host.AddCustomLogging()` looks definitely better. However I don't see how I can reach builder.Configuration through `builder`. I completely agree with everything else.

Comment: @nop Ohhh... apologize you are right. I've just overlooked this part: the `AddCustomLogging` is called on `builder.Host`, not the `builder` itself.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/B7bQ5GDN this is how it looks like after the updates but I wonder about a good way to make IConfiguration parameter optional

Comment: @nop Well the `UseSerilog` has [an overload](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/bf4ae072f7472d285c72f9a43f3eb4920e743110/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/SerilogWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L91) where you can provide a `configureLogger` action. This action receives a [`WebHostBuilderContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuildercontext) parameter which has access to the `Configuration`. I'm not sure that this can be helpful in this case.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PVHhfGnb this but dunno if it's good.

Comment: @nop It seems good to me, but you have to give it a try ;)

Comment: Works fine! Thanks once again mate! :)